# Fixar Título de Tabela

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma tabela que é gerada usando JSON:

```
<div id="divResult" ></div>
```

O *script* do JSON:

```
          $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/CadLevVisCont/ProcessaLevantamento")", { nmUF: catUF, nmRodovia: catRod, nmAno: catData }, function (data) {
                    $("#divResult").empty();
                    //Adicionar a tabela na div
                    table = "<table id='tableResult' class='table table-striped'><thead><tr><th >UF</th>";
                    table += "<th>BR</th><th >Cod. Levantamento</th><th>Sentido</th><th>km Inicial</th><th>km Final</th><th>Área Quebra de Bordo</th><th>Quantidade de Panelas</th>";
                    table += "<th>Trincamento</th><th>Trincamento Largo</th><th>Desgaste</th><th>IGG</th><th>ICS</th><th>Data do Levantamento</th><th>Obs</th></tr></thead></table>";

                    $("#divResult").append(table);

                    $(eval(data)).each(function (data) {
                        $("#tableResult").append("<tr ><td>"
                            + this.rUF + "</td><td >"
                            + this.rBR + "</td><td >"
                            + this.rCodLev + "</td><td >"
                            + this.rSentido + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rkmIni + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rkmFim + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rAreaQuebraBordo + "</td><td>"                            
                            + this.rQtdPanelas + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rPercet+ "</td><td>"
                            + this.rPercetLargo + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rDesgaste + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rIgg + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rIcs + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rData + "</td><td>"
                            + this.rObs + "</td></tr>");
                    });
                });
```

Como posso fazer com que o título da tabela fique fixo e os dados possam ser vistos através de uma barra de rolagem?

Comment: tenta colocar a propriedade title nessa div, acho que funciona.

Comment: Quando você diz título, quer dizer os cabeçalhos da tabela? Quer dizer, a linha com o `<th>`? Se for isso, é mesmo duplicata.

Comment: Percebi que é mesmo uma duplicada. É a mesma coisa que estou querendo fazer no post que o @Fernando indicou acima. Obrigado

Answer (score -2):

tenta colocar a propriedade title nessa div, acho que funciona.

exemplo: 
    `<div id="divResult" title="algum título"></div>`

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Aqui somos diferentes de um fórum. Aqui fornecemos respostas que sejam corretas, que possam ser comprovadas. Poderia elaborar um pouco mais sua resposta? Na forma atual sua resposta pode ser considerada como não útil.

Comment: Ok Rodrigo, desculpe, eu fui rápido demais ao converter em comentário. Complete sua resposta à vontade.

Comment: sem problema, é a primeira vez que estou comentando, ainda preciso me acostumar :)

Comment: Só que isso não é o que a pergunta pede, a ideia é deixar um título de uma tabela sempre fixo, enquanto o corpo da tabela tem rolamento.